# Would this work to debug an iPad app on the device?

Tags: ipad, debugging, certificate, profile, iphone-developer-program

I don't have a "Developer Profile". But I want to test my app on the iPad device. 
Are there any workrounds?

May e something like "[TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/)" but without the need of a profile. Something like a "temp" profile that is applied?

Is there a unversial profile for anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your device is jailbroken, there is no known way to test your app on a device without a developer profile.

Comment: is there a site like TestFlight which gives you a dev profile or when you upload the ipa they include it automatically?

Comment: There is a site called Apple Developer Connection which gives you a developer profile. Will cost you $99/year.

Comment: I know that but mayby there are some people out there who let you "rent" their profiles for testing ;)

Comment: @cocos2dbeginner I think renting your developer profile is against Apple's terms. :)